# UITextview delegate crash on keyboad did show notification

Tags: ios, delegates, crash, notifications

i am using UITextView in class Y and i had added Class Y in X as a subview.
Now, when editing starts in UItextview in sends on notification on UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, When it is sending notitfication two tasks need to be done
1. shift the whole view up by P units
2. Keyboard animation happens on its own

Here's the code i m doing...

Note :- NewTagDesc is a UIView

```
 @protocol TagDescDelegate;

@interface NewTagDesc : UIView <UITextViewDelegate>
{
    __unsafe_unretained id <TagDescDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id <TagDescDelegate> delegate;


//it crashes here, if you touch desc too freq. says its calling this method and this class is deallocated
-(void) noticeShowKeyboard:(NSNotification *)inNotification {
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(editingDescStarted:)]) {
        [delegate editingDescStarted:self];
    }
    keyboardVisible = YES;
}

-(void) noticeHideKeyboard:(NSNotification *)inNotification {
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(editingDescEnded:)]) {
        [delegate editingDescEnded:self];
    }
    keyboardVisible = NO;
}
```

now when notificaion is fired, my App crashes. Saying its been allocated and noticeShowKeyboard is called... :O ..... i have intuition that the error might be related to the way delegate is used, or notification. Can anybody help.... i am working on this issue since a long time

Comment: Can you please post the crash log from the xcode console? And maybe how you are subscribing to the notifications?

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(noticeShowKeyboard:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(noticeHideKeyboard:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

Comment: Sure... i will regenerate and paste crash log ....

Comment: i think r u synthesize delegate? just for conformation  :)

Comment: It crashes here...  -[NewTagDesc noticeShowKeyboard:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1f4a3b40 ... any clue now....

Comment: yes i am sythesize delegate. In class NewTagDesc ..like this               @synthesize delegate;

Comment: i think i have found it... i forgot to removeobservers now i have written code in 
-(void)dealloc{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                                  object:nil];
    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}
it must correct be i think...???

Comment: Hi guys, it even crashes now, after removing observers sometimes... :(